# value of type 'string' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of object'

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I've looked everywhere and I can't find help for my problems, its multiple errors.

Ok so what I'm trying to do is take 2 strings "FirstNameList" and "LastNameList" and put them together to make 1 word, a full name.

```
Public Class HorizonNameGenerator

    Dim UsableChars() As String
    Dim RandomClass() As Random
    Dim FirstNameList() = "Noah, Liam, Mason, Zack, James, Jack, Derick, Owen, Blain, Borris, Johnny, Joe, Joseph, Terry, William, Rory, John, Jason, Daryl, Alex, Josh, Wu, Gareth, Carl, Martin, Marty, Vincent, Vince, Vinny, Bobby, Bob, Paris, Jake, Gage, Jacob, Ethan, Simon, Elijah, Michael, Daniel, Thomas, Tom, Matthew, Declan, Logan, Lucas, Benjamain, Aiden, David, Andrew, Andy, Sam, Samuel, Carter, Henry, Nathan, Ed, Eddy"
    Dim LastNameList() = "Smith, Johnson, Williams, Jones, Brown, Davis, Miller, Wilson, Moore, Taylor, Anderson, Thomas, Jackson, White, Maris, Martin, Thompson, Garcia, Martinez, Robinson, Clark, Rodriguez, Lewis, Lee, Walker, Hall, Allen, Young, Hernandez, King, Wright, Lopez, Hill, Scott, Greens, Adams, Baker, Gonzalez, Nelson, Carter, Mitchell, Perez, Roberts, Turner, Phillips, Campbell, Parker, Evans, Edwards, Collins, Stewert"
    Dim FinalName() = ""
    Dim Number As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        UsableChars = Split(FirstNameList, ",")
        UsableChars = Split(LastNameList, ",")
        FinalName = ""
        Number = 0
        Number = RandomClass.Next(0, 59)
        FinalName = FinalName + UsableChars
    End Sub

End Class
```

However at bit "Noah, Liam, ect..." it says

> value of type 'string' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of object'

and same with the "Smith, Johnson, etc.."

also at the Dim FinaleName() = "" it say is under the

> " "

At the

```
UsableChars = Split(FirstNameList, ",")
UsableChars = Split(LastNameList, ",")
```

it says this

> value of type 'string' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'

under the "FirstNameList" and "LastNameList"

ALSO, under the

> RandomClass.Next(0, 59)

it says

> Next is not a member of 'System.Aray'

and finally under "FinalName + UsableChars"

it says

> Operator of "+" is not defined for types '1-dimensional array of object' and '1-dimensional array of String'

Can someone help me with this, I am new to this.

Comment: Construct the array directly (without splitting) `Dim FirstNameList() as String = {"Noah",  "Liam",  "Mason"}`

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better of writing the array rather than using split so you get something like this.

```
Dim FirstNames() As String = {"Noah", "Liam"}
Dim LastNames() As String = {"Bloggs", "Smith"}
```

Then you could use a random number generator to get a first name as last name similar to this.

```
Dim MyRandom As New Random

Dim FirstNameIndex As Integer = MyRandom.Next(0, FirstNames.Count)
Dim LastNameIndex As Integer = MyRandom.Next(0, LastNames.Count)
```

Then combine the two.

```
Dim FullName As String = FirstNames(FirstNameIndex) & " " & LastNames(LastNameIndex)
```

Hope this is what you're after. :)

Comment: Change `FirstNames.Count - 1` to `FirstNames.Count`, as the second parameter is **exclusive**.  Thus `MyRandom.Next(0, FirstNames.Count)` would give you values between 0 and (FirstNames.Count - 1) **inclusive**.

Comment: Been a long time since I've had to use a random so thanks for that, have updated my answer. :)

Comment: Ok I've done that, and all the errors are cleared up however, I'm not sure how I get it entered into the text box I want it to print into, so when you press "Generate" button it puts the names together into the text box above it, (the text box is called "BoxGenerated"

Comment: Hi. You would simply do.

BoxGenerated.Text = FullName

Comment: What type of control is this BoxGenerated - Is it a normal text box? Are you sure the name of is BoxGenerated?

Comment: Ah I got it to work, however its not doing what I want exactly, So you know how you have a first name and a last name, I want 1 first name and last name to join together and output to the box however its writing the list of Last names and firstnames out in the box, how do I fix this

Comment: Can you share the code to populate the box? Also if you put in a break point is the value of FullName the format you want?

Comment: This is beginning to like another question.

Comment: Hi, I don't have enough reputation to comment on your code below but the issue is that you have not close the quotation marks after each name when declaring them so it's one massive string. You have {"Fred, Jim"} it should be {"Fred","Jim"} also instead of Count - 1 in your random it should just be .count dont need the - 1 (see previous comments)

Answer (score 1):

You defined FirstNameList and LastNameList as arrays of objects. They should simply be strings since you are splitting them in the button click handler.

```
Dim FirstNameList As String = "Noah, Liam, Mason, Zack, James, Jack, Derick, Owen, Blain, Borris, Johnny, Joe, Joseph, Terry, William, Rory, John, Jason, Daryl, Alex, Josh, Wu, Gareth, Carl, Martin, Marty, Vincent, Vince, Vinny, Bobby, Bob, Paris, Jake, Gage, Jacob, Ethan, Simon, Elijah, Michael, Daniel, Thomas, Tom, Matthew, Declan, Logan, Lucas, Benjamain, Aiden, David, Andrew, Andy, Sam, Samuel, Carter, Henry, Nathan, Ed, Eddy"
Dim LastNameList As String = "Smith, Johnson, Williams, Jones, Brown, Davis, Miller, Wilson, Moore, Taylor, Anderson, Thomas, Jackson, White, Maris, Martin, Thompson, Garcia, Martinez, Robinson, Clark, Rodriguez, Lewis, Lee, Walker, Hall, Allen, Young, Hernandez, King, Wright, Lopez, Hill, Scott, Greens, Adams, Baker, Gonzalez, Nelson, Carter, Mitchell, Perez, Roberts, Turner, Phillips, Campbell, Parker, Evans, Edwards, Collins, Stewert"
```

You also use the UsableChars twice in a row in the button click handler. You will need to use different string arrays so that you can concatenate the first and last names.

Alternatively you could initialize the arrays as:

```
Dim FirstNameList() As String = {"Noah", " Liam", " Mason", " Zack", " James", " Jack", " Derick", " Owen", " Blain", " Borris", " Johnny", " Joe", " Joseph", " Terry", " William", " Rory", " John", " Jason", " Daryl", " Alex", " Josh", " Wu", " Gareth", " Carl", " Martin", " Marty", " Vincent", " Vince", " Vinny", " Bobby", " Bob", " Paris", " Jake", " Gage", " Jacob", " Ethan", " Simon", " Elijah", " Michael", " Daniel", " Thomas", " Tom", " Matthew", " Declan", " Logan", " Lucas", " Benjamain", " Aiden", " David", " Andrew", " Andy", " Sam", " Samuel", " Carter", " Henry", " Nathan", " Ed", " Eddy"}
Dim LastNameList() As String = {"Smith", " Johnson", " Williams", " Jones", " Brown", " Davis", " Miller", " Wilson", " Moore", " Taylor", " Anderson", " Thomas", " Jackson", " White", " Maris", " Martin", " Thompson", " Garcia", " Martinez", " Robinson", " Clark", " Rodriguez", " Lewis", " Lee", " Walker", " Hall", " Allen", " Young", " Hernandez", " King", " Wright", " Lopez", " Hill", " Scott", " Greens", " Adams", " Baker", " Gonzalez", " Nelson", " Carter", " Mitchell", " Perez", " Roberts", " Turner", " Phillips", " Campbell", " Parker", " Evans", " Edwards", " Collins", " Stewert"}
```

and avoided having to do the split function.

Answer (score 0):

For the Random error...

Change:

```
Dim RandomClass() As Random
```

To:

```
Dim RandomClass As New Random
```

As you're dealing with a single instance of Random, not an Array of Random.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim UsableChars() As String
Dim MyRandom As New Random
Dim FirstNameList() As String = {"Noah, Liam, Mason, Zack, James, Jack, Derick, Owen, Blain, Borris, Johnny, Joe, Joseph, Terry, William, Rory, John, Jason, Daryl, Alex, Josh, Wu, Gareth, Carl, Martin, Marty, Vincent, Vince, Vinny, Bobby, Bob, Paris, Jake, Gage, Jacob, Ethan, Simon, Elijah, Michael, Daniel, Thomas, Tom, Matthew, Declan, Logan, Lucas, Benjamain, Aiden, David, Andrew, Andy, Sam, Samuel, Carter, Henry, Nathan, Ed, Eddy"}
Dim LastNameList() As String = {"Smith, Johnson, Williams, Jones, Brown, Davis, Miller, Wilson, Moore, Taylor, Anderson, Thomas, Jackson, White, Maris, Martin, Thompson, Garcia, Martinez, Robinson, Clark, Rodriguez, Lewis, Lee, Walker, Hall, Allen, Young, Hernandez, King, Wright, Lopez, Hill, Scott, Greens, Adams, Baker, Gonzalez, Nelson, Carter, Mitchell, Perez, Roberts, Turner, Phillips, Campbell, Parker, Evans, Edwards, Collins, Stewert"}
Dim FinalName() As String = {""}
Dim Number As Integer = 0
Dim FirstNameIndex As Integer = MyRandom.Next(0, FirstNameList.Count - 1)
Dim LastNameIndex As Integer = MyRandom.Next(0, LastNameList.Count - 1)
Dim FullName As String = FirstNameList(FirstNameIndex) & " " & LastNameList(LastNameIndex)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = FullName
End Sub
```

Thats my code now, it sort of works, I want to be able to take 1 name from the "FirstNameList" and 1 name from "LastNameList" put it together and output it to "TextBox1" how do I do that.

So far all it does is write out all the names from both LastNameList and FirstnameList

Comment: This should be up in your original question.  **EDIT** up above to move this  up there...

Answer (score 0):

See my previous comments, but this is what you want.

```
Dim MyRandom As New Random
Dim FirstNameList() As String = {"Noah", "Liam", "Mason", "Zack", "James", "Jack", "Derick", "Owen", "Blain", "Borris", "Johnny", "Joe", "Joseph", "Terry", "William", "Rory", "John", "Jason", "Daryl", "Alex", "Josh", "Wu", "Gareth", "Carl", "Martin", "Marty", "Vincent", "Vince", "Vinny", "Bobby", "Bob", "Paris", "Jake", "Gage", "Jacob", "Ethan", "Simon", "Elijah", "Michael", "Daniel", "Thomas", "Tom", "Matthew", "Declan", "Logan", "Lucas", "Benjamain", "Aiden", "David", "Andrew", "Andy", "Sam", "Samuel", "Carter", "Henry", "Nathan", "Ed", "Eddy"}
Dim LastNameList() As String = {"Smith", "Johnson", "Williams", "Jones", "Brown", "Davis", "Miller", "Wilson", "Moore", "Taylor", "Anderson", "Thomas", "Jackson", "White", "Maris", "Martin", "Thompson", "Garcia", "Martinez", "Robinson", "Clark", "Rodriguez", "Lewis", "Lee", "Walker", "Hall", "Allen", "Young", "Hernandez", "King", "Wright", "Lopez", "Hill", "Scott", "Greens", "Adams", "Baker", "Gonzalez", "Nelson", "Carter", "Mitchell", "Perez", "Roberts", "Turner", "Phillips", "Campbell", "Parker", "Evans", "Edwards", "Collins", "Stewert"}
Dim FinalName() As String = {""}
Dim Number As Integer = 0
Dim FirstNameIndex As Integer = MyRandom.Next(0, FirstNameList.Count)
Dim LastNameIndex As Integer = MyRandom.Next(0, LastNameList.Count)
Dim FullName As String = FirstNameList(FirstNameIndex) & " " & LastNameList(LastNameIndex)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = FullName
End Sub
```

And if you wanted a new name on every button click you would just move some of the events to the button click event to have this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim FirstNameIndex As Integer = MyRandom.Next(0, FirstNameList.Count)
Dim LastNameIndex As Integer = MyRandom.Next(0, LastNameList.Count)
Dim FullName As String = FirstNameList(FirstNameIndex) & " " & LastNameList(LastNameIndex)
    TextBox1.Text = FullName
End Sub
```